# Type cast error in dispatchEvent

Tags: actionscript-3

I have three classes: A, B, C. class A dispatches a event, class B will handle this and then dispatch it C. However, I got this weird type casting error in B's dispatchEvent function, which looks like follows:

```
 public function handler(event:SomeEvent):void {
        removeEventListeners();
        dispatchEvent(event);
 }
```

If I change it to the following, then I don't get any error:

```
 public function handler(event:SomeEvent):void {
        removeEventListeners();
        var newEvent:SomeEvent = event.clone(); //create a clone of itself
        dispatchEvent(newEvent);
 }
```

Can anyone help me on this? Thank you.

Comment: Without seeing the code in A that dispatches the event and how B's event listeners are added to the event flow, it is hard to see the entire picture. Also, please provide the actual errors you're getting, since these are highly relevant in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Are you using a custom event? If you are, then you need to define the clone method. When you "re-dispatch" an event flash automatically clones the event and dispatches the clone. That's why when you changed your code to event.clone() it works. So, in a nutshell, your second implementation is correct.

If you don't want to have to write that extra bit of code you should implement the clone method. The documentation of EventDispatcher.dispatchEvent() explains this: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/

Answer (score 0):

You could do this.

```
public function handler(event:SomeEvent):void {
    removeEventListeners();
    dispatchEvent(event.clone);
 }
```

You need to clone the event. Once they are dispatched they can't be re-dispatched unless cloned. I am not sure why this is, perhaps something to do with handlers getting into infinite loops.

As heavily Involved stated you should implement a clone method on your event if it's custom. All this needs to do is return a new event of your type, copying any state/variables.